# Mysql trigger update table before insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

When I insert new row I have an error 'Can't update table 'contact' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.' What is the way to solve it?

I'm new in MySQL triggers. This is example of my table. One client may have a lot of contacts. But only one contact is important for one client

```
+-------+-------+--------+-------------+----------+
|  id   | name  | phone  | is_important| client_id|
+-------+-------+--------+-------------+----------+
|   1   | test1 | 9999999|    1        |     1    |
+-------+-------+--------+-------------+----------+
|   2   | test2 | 8888888|    0        |     1    |
+-------+-------+--------+-------------+----------+
```

I created trigger which change important status for contact if new row contain  is_important = 1;

```
CREATE TRIGGER clear_contact_priority
BEFORE INSERT
ON contact
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.is_important = 1)
THEN
UPDATE contact
  SET contact.is_important = 0
  WHERE contact.client_id = NEW.client_id AND contact.is_important = 1;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Your table does not seem to uniquely identify a client&is_important row - the id is the same in your example, Is there some way of uniquely identifying client&is_important rows?

Comment: @P.Salmon there were mistake. Of course id is unique. It is primary key.

Comment: You cannot do this in a trigger. You might be able to capture those you wish to update in a log table in the trigger for update later  or do the inserts in a procedure which then updates or from your front end whatever that is.